# Issue with python max number function

Tags: python

In the course I follow he made an example like this and when I applied it worked just fine but then when I added the input part myself it doesn't give out the max number correctly.

```
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
        return num1
    elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
        return num2
    else:
        return num3


first = input('first number ')
second = input('second number ')
third = input('third number ')
print(max_num(first, second, third))
```

Comment: Your numbers are still strings, not numbers (integers or floats). `input()` returns a string. And strings compare differently than numbers ("12" < "8" for strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `input()` function returns a String (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

You need to convert the number to `int` or `float`:

```
number = int(input('number '))
```